# Is there a relationship between the amount of time spent awake/asleep, and interstitial waste removal in the brain?

Tags: sleep, physiology, brain

With regard to the [glymphatic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glymphatic_system), is here a relationship between:

- The amount of time spent awake and the amount of interstitial waste accumulated in the brain?
- The amount of time spent asleep and the amount of interstitial waste removed?
- The time spent awake versus asleep, and the final amount of interstitial waste present at the end of a 24-hour period?

Comment: Hi Priter, Welcome at CogSci and what an interesting question. How did you come to this hypothesis? Could you provide us with a little context about the research you did?

Comment: I've slightly edited the question and linked a wiki page. You may wish to address Robin's comment still, though. They were mainly cosmetic changes imo.

Comment: @Robin I don't think it's correct to say it's as far along as a hypothesis yet. I have looked at several papers but to be honest I haven't found indications there is a relationship, nor have I found indications there isn't. My gut tells me it would make sense.

Comment: And I do not know if it's even possible to measure.